# Checking an identity matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, identity

I am writing a C program to check whether a matrix is identity. I'm not getting any output. Can anyone please find out what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int **matrix;
    int i,j,n,flag=0;
    matrix=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]!=1 && matrix[j][i]!=0)
                flag=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
        printf("\nIt is identity");
    else
        printf("\nIt isn't");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);matrix=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));`

Comment: You use the variable `n` before it's initialized. That leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: you have a debugger. PLease try using it.

Comment: `if(flag==1)` : there is no possibility that `flag` is set.

Comment: Ouch!! Guess that's it... Checking again. Thanks.

Comment: Also, your `break;` command is set to always execute on the first run through as it is not in the `if` block (you appear to have forgotten your `{}`). As such, you will only ever check your first element, not the entire matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors. For example you use variable n before its initialization

```
matrix=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
scanf("%d",&n);
```

There must be

```
scanf("%d",&n);
matrix=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

You never set variable flag to 1. So it always has value equal to 0 independing of the matrix values.

The break statement in this loop

```
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(matrix[i][j]!=1 && matrix[j][i]!=0)
            flag=0;
        break;
    }
```

have to be inside the compound statement of the if statement. Otherwise it has no sense.

For example the loops can look the following way

```
flag = 1;
for ( i = 0; flag && i < n; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; flag && j < n; j++ )
    {
        if ( matrix[i][j]!=1 && matrix[j][i]!=0 ) flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Take into account that blank lines between C constructions are very important elements of the code. They make the code more clear and readable.

Comment: I made the initialization error while copying the code here! Understood the part about variable flag. Didn't understand the part about break; where should I put it then? Sorry if I'm being naive, but I'm just a beginner!